# Open a native application from Angular page

Tags: android, angular, deep-linking

I want to suggest Android stores when a user opens my Angular site.
When I change my location from a click event it works correctly:

```
<button (click)="goToMarkets()">Go To Markets</button>

  goToMarkets(){
   window.location.href = 'market://...'
  }
```

[image]

But when I change my location in ngOnInit and other Angular hook methods nothing happen.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    window.location.href = 'market://...';
  }
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Isn't it that you can only do that when a user explicitly clicks something (so in the click handler), and not somewhere else in the background? This is to prevent random sites to kick you over to some other app without a question, which is actually a good thing.

Comment: @AlexBiro No because I test it with other domains such as www.google.com and it redirects successfully

Comment: Yes, but that's a normal web page, where `market://...` is an app. The important difference is the URL scheme.

Comment: Ok,so what should I do?how can I solve this?

Comment: The point is that you can't, Chrome prevents that on purpose. It doesn't want random web pages opening random apps without the user explicitly clicking something. So your only choice is to create links, and ask the user to click on them.